# SQLite Database not being created in Android Studio when the project is run on a new machine or if the Database folder is deleted

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-emulator

I have built an application where using fusedlocation provider I get the location and based on the location on I display a report card of a particular location from an SQLiteDatabase.

The database worked fine initially but then when I ran the same android project on another machine it wasn't creating the database. Once the database folder was being created by Android in Device File Explorer -> Data -> Data -> Package Name -> Databases. I was manually loading the following Database file by right clicking on the the Database folder and clicking upload.
Database file link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/197MHiLl8nvFZ5eHStrBR9WfeYvQTtDKm/view?usp=sharing
To try to understand what the issue is I deleted the database folder from my project on my own machine as well and now the Database folder isn't created on my machine as well.

Before you mark this as a duplicate I have already tried the methods from the following questions but it still didn't work.
[Android SQLite database table not being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773083/android-sqlite-database-table-not-being-created)
[sqlite database not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888227/sqlite-database-not-created)
https://alvinalexander.com/android/sqliteopenhelper-does-not-call-oncreate-failing-database

Please find my code below:
DatabaseHelper.java

```
package edu.cpsc6150.co2ut;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DATABASE_NAME = "states";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "States_Report";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String STATE_NAME = "name";
    public static final String STATE_GRADE = "grade";
    public static final String EXTREME_HEAT = "heat";
    public static final String DROUGHT = "Drought";
    public static final String WILDFIRES = "wildfires";
    public static final String INLAND_FLOODING = "inlandflooding";
    public static final String COASTAL_FLOODING = "coastalflooding";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENTS = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + STATE_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + STATE_GRADE + " TEXT,"
            + EXTREME_HEAT + " TEXT,"
            + DROUGHT + " TEXT,"
            + WILDFIRES + " TEXT,"
            + INLAND_FLOODING + " TEXT,"
            + COASTAL_FLOODING + " TEXT)";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //Log.d("table", CREATE_TABLE_STUDENTS);
    }   //end DatabaseHelper constructor

    /**
     * Functionality: Creates tables
     * PreConditions: needs table names and column names
     * PostConditions: Table is created
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STUDENTS);
    }   //end onCreate method

    /**
     * Functionality: Drop existing table and create new table if table already exists
     * PreConditions: Database name, oldversion number and newVersion number are required to create a new table
     * PostConditions: Old table should be dropped and new table should be created
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_NAME + "'");
        onCreate(db);
    }   //end onUpgrade method
    /*
    public long addStudentDetail(String state, String grade, String heat, String drought, String wildfires, String iflooding, String cflooding) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Creating content values
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(STATE_NAME, state);
        values.put(STATE_GRADE, grade);
        values.put(EXTREME_HEAT, heat);
        values.put(DROUGHT, drought);
        values.put(WILDFIRES, wildfires);
        values.put(INLAND_FLOODING, iflooding);
        values.put(COASTAL_FLOODING, cflooding);
       // insert row in students table
        long insert = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        return insert;
    }*/

    /**
     * Functionality: Get data from database and Update UI
     * PreConditions: requires existing populated database
     * PostConditions: Update reportcard in the UI from the database
     */
    public String[] getData(String state) {
        /*SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from States_Report where name = '"+state+"'", null );
        return res;*/
        String State = state;
        String[] name = new String[7];
        String password;
        //SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {DatabaseHelper.STATE_NAME,DatabaseHelper.STATE_GRADE,DatabaseHelper.EXTREME_HEAT,DatabaseHelper.DROUGHT,DatabaseHelper.WILDFIRES,DatabaseHelper.INLAND_FLOODING,DatabaseHelper.COASTAL_FLOODING};
        Cursor cursor =db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,columns,"name = '"+state+"' ",null,null,null,null);
        StringBuffer buffer= new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            name[0] =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.STATE_NAME));
            name[1] =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.STATE_GRADE));
            name[2] =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.EXTREME_HEAT));
            name[3] =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.DROUGHT));
            name[4] =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.WILDFIRES));
            name[5] =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.INLAND_FLOODING));
            name[6] =cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COASTAL_FLOODING));
        }


        return name;
    }   //end getData method
}   //end DatabaseHelper class
```

ReportCardActivity.java (Which is like the MainActivity.java for this particular feature)

```
package edu.cpsc6150.co2ut;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class ReportCardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = ReportCardActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @BindView(R.id.location_result)
    TextView txtLocationResult;

    @BindView(R.id.btn_start_location_updates)
    Button btnStartUpdates;

    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 5000;
    private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private Location mCurrentLocation;

    private Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private TextView statedisplay, gradedisplay, heat, drought, wildfires, inlandFlooding,coastalFlooding;

    /**
     * Functionality: Instantiates the DatabaseHelper class and other UI Components like textviews
     * PreConditions: DatabaseHelper and textviews must be declared
     * PostConditions: Textviews are assigned and DatabaseHelper initialized
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_card);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
        statedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statedisplay);
        gradedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradedisplay);
        heat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heat);
        drought = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drought);
        wildfires = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wildfires);
        inlandFlooding = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inlandFlooding);
        coastalFlooding = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coastalFlooding);
        // initialize the necessary libraries
        init();

        // restore the values from saved instance state
        restoreValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
    }   //end onCreate method


    /**
     * Functionality: Initializes the necessary libraries to get location updates
     * PreConditions: Library's required for the location updates must be declared
     * PostConditions: All necessary Libraries are intialized
     */
    private void init() {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            /**
             * Functionality: Updates Last location on receiving location updates
             * PreConditions: Needs to receive locationResult as a parameter
             * PostConditions: Return updated last location to the UI
             */

            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                // location is received
                mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();


                updateLocationUI();
            }
        };

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }   //end init method

    /**
     * Functionality: Restores the savedState of the activity
     * PreConditions: Needs the instance state to be saved
     * PostConditions: Retrieve the saved state and update the UI
     */
    private void restoreValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("is_requesting_updates")) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("is_requesting_updates");
            }

            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("last_known_location")) {
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("last_known_location");
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }   //end restoreValuesFromBundle method



    /**
     * Functionality: Update the UI displaying the location data
     * PreConditions: Requires the current location
     * PostConditions: Updates the UI with the current location and the states report card from the database
     */
    String state;
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try{
                List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    String output[] = databaseHelper.getData(state);
                    statedisplay.setText("  State: "+output[0]);
                    gradedisplay.setText("  Average: "+output[1]);
                    heat.setText("  Extreme Heat: "+output[2]);
                    drought.setText("  Drought: "+output[3]);
                    wildfires.setText("  Wildfires: "+output[4]);
                    inlandFlooding.setText("  Inland Flooding: "+output[5]);
                    coastalFlooding.setText("  Coastal Flooding: "+output[6]);
                    /*Cursor rs = databaseHelper.getData(state);
                    if (rs.moveToFirst()){
                        // do the work

                        String username = rs.getString(1);
                        String password = rs.getString(2);

                        //String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.STATE_NAME));
                        //String phon = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.STATE_GRADE));

                        statedisplay.setText(username);
                        gradedisplay.setText(password);

                    }*/

                    //arrayList = databaseHelper.getAllStudentsList();
                    //tvnames.setText("");
                /*for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
                     tvnames.setText(tvnames.getText().toString()+", "+arrayList.get(i));
                }*/

                }
                else {
                    // do your stuff
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }   //end try-catch block
            txtLocationResult.setText(
                    getString(R.string.welcome_message,state)
            );


            // location last updated time
        }
    }   //end updateLocationUI method

    /**
     * Functionality: Saves the Activities current state
     * PreConditions: Needs the values of mCurrentLocation and mRequestingLocationUpdates
     * PostConditions: The Instance state should be saved to the Bundle
     */
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("is_requesting_updates", mRequestingLocationUpdates);
        outState.putParcelable("last_known_location", mCurrentLocation);
    }   //end onSaveInstanceState method




    /**
     * Functionality: Starting location updates
     * PreConditions: Check whether location settings are satisfied
     * PostConditions: Location updates will be requested
     */
    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        mSettingsClient
                .checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Started location updates!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //noinspection MissingPermission
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                                mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

                        updateLocationUI();
                    }   //end onSuccess method
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                        switch (statusCode) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Attempting to upgrade " +
                                        "location settings ");
                                try {
                                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                    // result in onActivityResult().
                                    ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                    rae.startResolutionForResult(ReportCardActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                                }   //end try-catch block
                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                String errorMessage = "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " +
                                        "fixed here. Fix in Settings.";
                                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);

                                Toast.makeText(ReportCardActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }   //end switch statement
                        updateLocationUI();
                    }   //end onFailure method
                });
    }   //end startLocationUpdates method

    /**
     * Functionality: OnClick will start receiving location updates
     * PreConditions: Permissions must be granted
     * PostConditions: Location Updates started
     */
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_start_location_updates)
    public void startLocationButtonClick() {
        // Requesting ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION using Dexter library
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
                        startLocationUpdates();
                    }   //end onPermissionGranted method

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // open device settings when the permission is
                            // denied permanently
                            openSettings();
                        }
                    }   //end onPermuissionDenied method

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }   //end onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown method
                }).check();
    }   //end startLocationButtonClick method


    /**
     * Functionality: Stop or pause location updates when the app pauses
     * PreConditions: FusedLocationClient must be intialized
     * PostConditions: Stop Location updates
     */
    public void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // Removing location updates
        mFusedLocationClient
                .removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    /**
                     * Functionality:
                     * PreConditions:
                     * PostConditions:
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location updates stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    }   //end stopLocationUpdates method

    /**
     * Functionality: Check whether user has granted permissions or not
     * PreConditions: Needs requestCode, resultCode and data as parameters
     * PostConditions: Log the ActivityResult as an error log
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Log.e(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                        // Nothing to do. startLocationupdates() gets called in onResume again.
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.e(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                        break;
                }   //end switch statement
                break;
        }   //end switch statement
    }   //end onActivityResult method

    /**
     * Functionality: Open settings if permissions is denied
     * PreConditions: Settings URI
     * PostConditions: Open Application details settings page
     */
    private void openSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(
                Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }   //end openSettings method

    /**
     * Functionality: Check for permissions again onResume
     * PreConditions: App must be paused or stopped before this function is called
     * PostConditions: onResume the locationupdates must be resume and the UI must be updated
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Resuming location updates depending on button state and
        // allowed permissions
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates && checkPermissions()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }   //end onResume()

    /**
     * Functionality: Checks if permission to access location is granted
     * PreConditions: Permission must be mentioned in the manifest file
     * PostConditions: Return permission granted if Uses-Permission is mentioned in the activity file
     */
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }   //end checkPermissions method

    /**
     * Functionality: Stops location updates when the application is paused
     * PreConditions: Application must be paused
     * PostConditions: Location updates must be stopped
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            // pausing location updates
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }   //end onPause method
}   //end ReportCardActivity class
```

Let me know if you need any more information regarding the code or dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I have attached a solution where you just need to add two lines of code to the ReportCardActivity.java code. The two lines of code to be added are commented as "//add this line" and have a line of astrix (*) before and after it.

```
 private Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
*********************************************************
    SQLiteDatabase database; //add this line
*********************************************************
    private TextView statedisplay, gradedisplay, heat, drought, wildfires, inlandFlooding,coastalFlooding;

    /**
     * Functionality: Instantiates the DatabaseHelper class and other UI Components like textviews
     * PreConditions: DatabaseHelper and textviews must be declared
     * PostConditions: Textviews are assigned and DatabaseHelper initialized
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_card);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
*********************************************************
        database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //add this line
*********************************************************
        statedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statedisplay);
        gradedisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gradedisplay);
        heat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heat);
        drought = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drought);
        wildfires = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wildfires);
        inlandFlooding = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inlandFlooding);
        coastalFlooding = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coastalFlooding);
        // initialize the necessary libraries
        init();

        // restore the values from saved instance state
        restoreValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
    }   //end onCreate method
```

One you paste the code run the application. This should create the database directory in the Device File Explorer -> Data -> Data -> Package Name directory.

The database folder might not be visible immediately. You may have to restart android studio after you run the app once.

When you restart android studio and go to Device File Explorer -> Data -> Data -> Package Name directory the databases directory should be created.

Once it is created right click on the databases folder and click upload then upload the database file you have provided in the link.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the database is being created **BUT** you don't appear to be populating it.

Using your **Databasehelper** (with **addStudentDetail** uncommented as the only change) then using :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDBHelper.addStudentDetail("STATE1","GRADE1","HIGH","YES","NO","NO","NO");
        mDBHelper.addStudentDetail("STATE1","GRADE2","HIGH","YES","NO","NO","NO");
        mDBHelper.addStudentDetail("STATE1","GRADE3","HIGH","YES","NO","NO","NO");
        mDBHelper.addStudentDetail("STATE1","GRADE4","HIGH","YES","NO","NO","NO");
        for (String s: mDBHelper.getData("STATE1")){
            Log.d("INFO",s);
        }
    }
}
```

results in :-

```
12-05 16:38:19.211 3764-3764/? D/INFO: STATE1
12-05 16:38:19.211 3764-3764/? D/INFO: GRADE4
12-05 16:38:19.211 3764-3764/? D/INFO: HIGH
12-05 16:38:19.211 3764-3764/? D/INFO: YES
12-05 16:38:19.211 3764-3764/? D/INFO: NO
12-05 16:38:19.211 3764-3764/? D/INFO: NO
12-05 16:38:19.211 3764-3764/? D/INFO: NO
```

I can't see anywhere in your code where you are adding data to the database. rather you just try to get data using `String output[] = databaseHelper.getData(state);`, which will  retrieve nothing as there is no data.

Comment: I'm manually adding a database file which already contains data. I have provided the link of the database file in the section above.