# Android Studio SQLiteOpenHelper - Oncreate

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I was trying to create a DataBase where I needed My DataBase to be created while I open My Application Not to be triggered by any Onclick Methods.
I could really use some Help
?

I tried to call it via Main class onCreate But It exits the application.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DataBaseHelper dbh = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
    dbh.onCreate();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite Database not being created in Android Studio when the project is run on a new machine or if the Database folder is deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187813/sqlite-database-not-being-created-in-android-studio-when-the-project-is-run-on-a)

Answer (score 1):

In short you don't try to call the `onCreate` method. Doing so, like you have, will call it when the database hasn't actually been created and hence you will probably get a null pointer exception.

More specifically when you instantiate the DataBaseHelper it doesn't actually create the database, it only does that when you try to access the database and  either `getWritableDatabase` or `getReadableDatabase` are called in which case the database is opened.

- note that  `getReadableDatabase` will get a writable database. The subtle difference is that getReadableDatabase may, in some rare circumstances, return a database that can only be read. as per

  - > This will be the same object returned by getWritableDatabase() unless some problem, such as a full disk, requires the database to be opened read-only. In that case, a read-only database object will be returned.
  - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#getReadableDatabase()

If in the process of opening the database, the database does not exist then the `onCreate` method is called **after the database has been created**  and the SQLiteDatabase passed to the `onCreate` method is an existing database. The `onCreate` method then allows you to add your tables, indexes, views, triggers to the database.

- When the database is created (before invoking `onCreate` it will have 2 tables **sqlite_master** (the schema) and **android_metadata** (stores the locale of the device), these are system tables).

**A FIX**

Don't call the `onCreate` method, rather let the **SQLiteOpenHelper** invoke the `onCreate` method as and when it needs to.

You can force this, without doing anything else, by using either `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`. e.g. you could have :-

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DataBaseHelper dbh = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this); /* NOTE only instantiates the helper, it does not create the database */
    //dbh.onCreate(); /*<<<<<<<<<< COMMENTED OUT */
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase(); /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to force an open and if need be the one-time creation of the database*/
}
```

**Demonstration**

The following is an example that demonstrates the above. The DataBaseHelper is:-

```
class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_FILENAME = "the_database.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_NUMBER = 1;

    DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_FILENAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION_NUMBER);
    }

    /*
        NOTE onCreate is only called when an attempt is made to get a writable/readable SQLiteDatabase
        in which case the database is create by the SQLiteOpenHelper.
        If the database already exists then it will not be called. As such onCreate is called only
        once for the lifetime of the database.

     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        /* Demonstrate the database components BEFORE creating any user defined components */
        /* YOU WOULD NOT TYPICALLY DO THIS */
        Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
        /* Create the user components */
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS the_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public boolean doesDBExist(Context context, String tagExtra) {
        String TAG = "DBDEBUG" + tagExtra;
        String path = context.getDatabasePath(this.getDatabaseName()).getPath();
        boolean rv = false;
        if (context.getDatabasePath(this.getDatabaseName()).exists()) {
            rv = true;
            Log.d(TAG,"The database " + this.getDatabaseName() + " exists. It is located at " + path);
        } else {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "\n\tThe databases folder " + context.getDatabasePath(this.getDatabaseName()).getParentFile().getPath());
            rv = false;
            if (context.getDatabasePath(this.getDatabaseName()).getParentFile().exists()) {
                sb.append(" exists.");
            } else {
                sb.append(" does not exist.");
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"The database " + this.getDatabaseName() + " does not exist as location " + path + sb.toString());
        }
        return rv;
    }
}
```

i.e. a pretty basic class that extends SQLiteOpenhelper other than

1. the `doesDBExist` method which checks whether or not the underlying file that is the database exists, logging the result.
2. the `onCreate` method, before creating the single table, extracts the existing components from the sqlite_master table (the database schema).

The activity code used is similar to yours but has additional method calls/code to log info. :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseHelper dbh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbh = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        dbh.doesDBExist(this,"STG01"); /* before opening the database see if it exists */
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase(); /* should open and create db if required */
        dbh.doesDBExist(this,"STG02"); /* should now exist */
        Cursor csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr);
        csr.close();
    }
}
```

**Result**

When run as a new install then the log contains:-

```
2022-11-26 09:01:25.121 D/DBDEBUGSTG01: The database the_database.db does not exist as location /data/user/0/a.a.so74564168sqliteoncreatedemo/databases/the_database.db
        The databases folder /data/user/0/a.a.so74564168sqliteoncreatedemo/databases exists.
        
        
2022-11-26 09:01:25.151 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@cf2ef01
2022-11-26 09:01:25.151 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-11-26 09:01:25.151 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-26 09:01:25.152 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-11-26 09:01:25.152 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-11-26 09:01:25.152 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-11-26 09:01:25.152 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-11-26 09:01:25.153 I/System.out: }
2022-11-26 09:01:25.153 I/System.out: <<<<<


2022-11-26 09:01:25.162 D/DBDEBUGSTG02: The database the_database.db exists. It is located at /data/user/0/a.a.so74564168sqliteoncreatedemo/databases/the_database.db


2022-11-26 09:01:25.163 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40841a6
2022-11-26 09:01:25.163 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-11-26 09:01:25.164 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-26 09:01:25.164 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-11-26 09:01:25.164 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-11-26 09:01:25.164 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-11-26 09:01:25.164 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-11-26 09:01:25.164 I/System.out: }
2022-11-26 09:01:25.164 I/System.out: 1 {
2022-11-26 09:01:25.165 I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-26 09:01:25.165 I/System.out:    name=the_table
2022-11-26 09:01:25.165 I/System.out:    tbl_name=the_table
2022-11-26 09:01:25.165 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2022-11-26 09:01:25.165 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE the_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 TEXT)
2022-11-26 09:01:25.165 I/System.out: }
2022-11-26 09:01:25.166 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- So after instantiating DataBaseHelperm the database does not exist (first lines before the spaces).
- when the `getWritableDatabase` method is called then as per the second set the `onCreate` method is called automatically and the schema is dumped and the only table that exists is **android_metadata** (actually sqlite_master exists as well as it must).

  - android_metadata is a table unique to android and embedded SQLite API, it stores the locale enabling it's management from the SQLite perspective.
- the 2nd call to `doesDBExist` now shows that the file does exist.
- last the extract from sqlite_master shows that now the **the_table** table exists and was created by the `onCreate` method.

**Subsequent Run**

If the App is run again then the log contains:-

```
2022-11-26 09:22:58.583  D/DBDEBUGSTG01: The database the_database.db exists. It is located at /data/user/0/a.a.so74564168sqliteoncreatedemo/databases/the_database.db


2022-11-26 09:22:58.587  D/DBDEBUGSTG02: The database the_database.db exists. It is located at /data/user/0/a.a.so74564168sqliteoncreatedemo/databases/the_database.db


2022-11-26 09:22:58.587  I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@9c8df94
2022-11-26 09:22:58.587  I/System.out: 0 {
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    rootpage=3
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out: }
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out: 1 {
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    type=table
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    name=the_table
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    tbl_name=the_table
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    rootpage=4
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE the_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 TEXT)
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out: }
2022-11-26 09:22:58.588  I/System.out: <<<<<
```

i.e. The database exists and has been retained/persisted. `onCreate` was not called (as the database now exists) and the table exists.